# Unable to register the subscrition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I am new to **Windows Azure**.

I got a subscription to use Windows Azure, However i am not able to publish my sample web site.

The Error is,

**This subscription not registered use to following resources: Website The remote server returned unexpected response(400). Bad request.**

My question is, How to register the subscription?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Senthilnathan Kumarasamy.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue.

What you need to do is to logon into the Azure web console and create a web site through by clicking:

New > Compute > WebSite > Quick Create.

Then from within Visual Studio when you try to publish your web app, you will see the account in the import wizard dialog.